# Have I interpreted machine language instruction correctly?

Tags: assembly, lc3

[image]

This is my LC-3 coded interoperation of the image given

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R1, R7, #29
ADD R2, R1, #14
ST R2, R7, #27
AND R2, R2, #0
ADD R2, R2, #5
STR R2, R1, #14
LDI R3, R7, #23
.END
```

Please tell me where i have gone wrong since when i assemble this code it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice the first address given in the table — `x30F6`.

If you're trying to reproduce that you'll have to use a different approach to locating the code.  One such approach is to use `.ORIG x30F6` (while another approach is to insert space after a `.ORIG x3000`, e.g. `.BLKW xF6`, so that the next instruction lands on `x30F6`.)

Next, you have decoded the first instruction correctly as opcode `LEA` with the correct register destination (`R1`), but the `LEA` instruction's format has only two operands, whereas you have 3 operands, so that is incorrect.

Next, the `ADD` looks good.

Next, you have done the same error as with the first `LEA`, in decoding the `ST` opcode and source register `R2` correctly, but have decoded the rest as 2 more operands, where `ST` only has one more operand.

Pay closer attention to the blue underlining, it is showing you the grouping and count of the fields that describe each instruction's operands.

Comment: So how would i correctly interoperate the first instruction and third. I am taking an online course at my college and the professor has only gone over the ADD,AND, and NOT opcodes. The rest have have tried using the principles of the the 3 mentioned opcodes to figure out the rest. And it the help would be appreciated. I am not sure if he forgot to upload the rest before handing this assignment out but wont replay to my emails.

Comment: https://www.cs.unca.edu/~bruce/Spring14/109/Resources/lc3-isa.pdf